# If my ip is 192.168.0.108 how can I access a virtual machine within a range of 192.168.1.0/24?

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, subnet

My Network range is : 192.168.0.0/24

I got a VM with static IP preconfigured within the range of 192.168.1.0/24

I started the VM but don't have access to the netwrok. Don't know the password to login also.

I would like to know how can I ping the machine from my local PC to other netwrok?

Comment: This is very confusing.  What is the real objective?  Just to ping the VM to “prove” that it is running?  Do you want / need to login to it?  How do you expect to do that if you don’t know the password?  Does the VM provide a service (e.g., web server or file server) that needs to be accessed?  If so, just from your machine, or from others?  Do you have privileges to reconfigure your real machine?  Is it statically configured or DHCP?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Can you create and configure other VMs (from scratch)? How much of the VM’s configuration do you know (e.g., do you know its routing table?). Are there any firewalls in the picture?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: (Question relayed from Hongkie): Where is the VM? in your own laptop or stored in your company server?

Answer (score 0):

temporarily, you can change the subnet from /24 (aka 255.255.255.0) to 255.255.0.0... it should help with the ping issue. let me know if you still cannot ping

Comment: Not a terrible idea,  but if, as the question says, the VM is preconfigured within the range of 192.168.1.0/24, it might refuse to send a reply packet to 192.168.0.108.

Comment: where is the VM ? in your own laptop or stored in your company server ?

Comment: In my own laptop

Answer (score 0):

Is the network connection of your virtual machine set to bridged or nat? If you want the VM to be a full member of your private network you need to set it to bridged and change the IP to something starting with 192.168.0. Also you should change the gateway to the same one your host OS uses, probably 192.168.0.1

Comment: I tried both bridged and NAT. Can we change the IP in Vmware-WOrkstation settings? Am not able to login to the system. At this case, how can we change IP and gateway?

Comment: Why can't you log in? You can't set the IP in VMware settings. If you can not change the network configuration of the VM you could instead change the configuration of your host machine. To be able to ping the VM you could set networking mode to bridged and then give your host machine an IP starting with 192.168.1

Comment: Now Am using Wifi hotspot and getting an IP - 192.168.43.147. How will I configure my host machine to get an IP in range of 192.168.1.0/24 ?  Am using an android phone for hotspot

Comment: You need to change the ip address of your ethernet adapter, not the wifi connection. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-ip-address-windows-10

Comment: Why not just set up a small Linux router VM, like IPfire.  IPfire can route from your external IP address, the .147, to the 1.0 subnet.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing some comments: Here is the better answer:

As you are using vmware workstation, and android phone for hotspot (aka internet router), the only practical way is to **create another vm**

This vm (i.e dummy vm) should have static ip address 192.168.1.1. This dummy vm is used to access 192.168.1.0.

Use windows 7 or windows XP that has small disk print. I installed a "dummy" windows 7 and the space is only 8GB.

Comment: After installing a new VM I got an IP of 192.168.43.12 . and gatway of 192.168.43.1 .   Now how can I access 192.18.1.1/24 !!!!

Comment: because the new VM is using existing networking. Turn off the VM, and create a custom networking with new range range 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255... Here are 2 links how to create custom networking. To simplify, you can copy from NAT networking but replace the ip range.... https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_custom.html

.....

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html